# In Excel - find the second (or nth) closest location from a list of coordinates

Tags: excel, distance, lookup

For example, the below table shows origin coordinates in the blue highlighted cells and possible destinations in the green highlighted cells.

[image: Coordinates table]
The 'ClosestSiteID' field identifies the SiteID of the destination coordinate set that is closest to the origin coordinate set.

For reference, the formula used in cell A2 is:

`=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,SIN((RADIANS(G$2:G$11-$D2))/2)^2+SIN((RADIANS(H$2:H$11-$E2))/2)^2*COS(RADIANS(G$2:G$11))*COS(RADIANS($D2))),$F$2:$F$11)`

How do I modify this formula to select the second or nth closest destination for a given origin to populate column B?

Answer (score 0):

That construction is, in general, not readily adaptable so as to give the second, third, etc. smallest value. In this case, however, we can achieve the required amendment if we incorporate the value in `A2`:

`=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,99^99^(F2:F11=A2)*(SIN((RADIANS(G$2:G$11-$D2))/2)^2+SIN((RADIANS(H$2:H$11-$E2))/2)^2*COS(RADIANS(G$2:G$11))*COS(RADIANS($D2)))),$F$2:$F$11)`

Regards